# Compile time binding a C++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, corba

I am trying to figure out how to get a C++ template to use a look-up table to perform its functions, but at compile time not run time. I am having trouble putting it into words, so here's an example, and the ugly template + preprocessor macro combination that I have so far:

```
template<class T_POD, class T_Corba>
inline void c_to_corba_base(T_POD &In, CORBA::Any &Out) {
    Out <<= static_cast<T_Corba>(In);
}

#define C_TO_CORBA_PAIR(T_POD, T_CORBA) \
inline void c_to_corba(T_POD &In, CORBA::Any &Out) { \
    c_to_corba_base<T_POD, T_CORBA>(In, Out); \
}

C_TO_CORBA_PAIR(short, CORBA::Short)
C_TO_CORBA_PAIR(long, CORBA::Long)
C_TO_CORBA_PAIR(double, CORBA::Double)
// etc.
```

So you can see, it typecasts `A` to `B` to get `C`. `C` is always `CORBA::Any`. But `B` depends on `A` (known at compile time).

I've done some research and it looks like [`Boost::MPL::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/bind.html) may do what I need (and we already require Boost) but I do not understand the syntax. It could have all been done in the macro, but I'd rather have it as "real" templates if it can be done.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I gather there's a `<<=` operator that understands how to handle a left-hand-side which is a reference to a `CORBA::Any` and a right-hand-side which is in the set [`CORBA::Short`, `CORBA::Long`, `CORBA::Double`... etc.]  So is there a good reason why you are introducing this `c_to_corba` function, rather than enhancing `<<=` targeting a `CORBA::Any` to accept the simple types?

Comment: It's the pair to `corba_to_c` which would be a little more complicated. I asked the same question from the person I was trying to help with this and he had some problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this better?

```
template<typename> struct CorbaTypeMap;
template<> struct CorbaTypeMap<short>  { typedef CORBA::Short  type; };
template<> struct CorbaTypeMap<long>   { typedef CORBA::Long   type; };
template<> struct CorbaTypeMap<double> { typedef CORBA::Double type; };

template<typename T_POD>
inline void c_to_corba(T_POD &In, CORBA::Any &Out) {
    Out <<= static_cast< /* typename */ CorbaTypeMap<T_POD>::type >(In);
}
```

I don't think you'll need that `typename` keyword, because `static_cast` always needs a type, but if you get an error that'll probably be the fix.

Comment: That looks great. Would you mind explaining the empty `struct` at the top, etc?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco: It's not an empty struct, it's just a declaration of a struct template (no definition at all, empty or otherwise).  The declaration is necessary because the next three lines are specializations, but you can't specialize a template that hasn't been declared yet.